# Array no se muestra hasta recargar la pagina en react native

Tags: react-native

Buenasn noches, me encuentro haciendo una practica y me estoy enfrentando a un issue que no se como resolver, cuando envio por context un arreglo de objetos  en mi componente hijo no lo renderiza hasta que guardo el codigo con ctrl + s  y ahi renderiza mis cards, la verdad tengo todo el dia queriendo resolver eso y ya no tengo ideas, epero que alguien que ya se haya enfrentado a eso pueda orientarme.`

```css
const DataTableVentas =  () => {
  const { sales, property, getCompany} = useContext(Context); 
  
  const CardsRender = ({item, index}) => {
    return(
      <Card style={styles.card} key={index}>
        {/* <Image source={{uri: "http://50.116.19.48:8888/sites/default/files/" + property.logo.filename}} style={{height: 30, width: 20}} />  */}
        <Layout style={styles.dataInformation}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item}</Text> 
          <Text>Menudeo</Text>
        </Layout>
        <Layout style={styles.dataInformation}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>0</Text>
          <Text>Flotilla</Text>
        </Layout>
        <Layout style={styles.dataInformation}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>?</Text>
          <Text>Total</Text>
        </Layout>
      </Card> 
    )

  }
```

```html
  let salesByemp = []
  const getQuerySales = async (emp) => {
    let inicial = moment(date.startDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    let final = moment(date.endDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    const tk = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');

    return axios.post(API_URL + 'elk/broker', {
      'type': '_count',
      'index': VENTAS_INDEX,
      'query': createQueryByEmpAndType(emp.nid, 'Menudeo', inicial, final),
    }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': tk
      },
      withCredentials: true
    
      }).then((response) => {
        salesByemp.push(response.data.count)
        setSales(salesByemp)
        
        // const data = [ 
        //   {logo:emp.logo},
        //   {heigth:emp.heigth},
        //   {width:emp.width},
        //   {nid: emp.nid},
        //   {name: emp.nombre},

        // ]

        // let prop = Object.assign(data)
        // setProperty(prop)
        
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error, "error getquerysales")
      })
```

`
posdata: tengo un codigo comentado, porque me gustaria enviar todas las propiedades y solo renderizar el  data.count junto con lo demas y no hacerlo por separado pero me sale que no es iterable el arreglo.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que estás enfrentando, donde el componente hijo no se renderiza hasta que guardas el código con Ctrl + S, puede deberse a que la actualización de **sales** en el estado no se está propagando correctamente hacia abajo en la jerarquía de componentes.

Una posible solución es **asegurarte de que sales se actualice adecuadamente antes de que el componente hijo intente renderizarlo**. Para hacer esto, puedes utilizar el **hook useEffect para observar cambios en sales y asegurarte de que esté actualizado antes de renderizar el componente hijo**.

Aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo puedes modificar tu código para incluir useEffect:

```
const DataTableVentas = () => {
  const { sales, property, getCompany } = useContext(Context);
  
  const CardsRender = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <Card style={styles.card} key={index}>
        {/* Resto del código de renderización de la tarjeta */}
      </Card>
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Realiza la lógica que actualiza salesByemp y llama a setSales aquí
    // Puedes mover la lógica de getQuerySales a este punto
    const fetchData = async () => {
      let inicial = moment(date.startDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
      let final = moment(date.endDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
      const tk = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token');

      axios
        .post(
          API_URL + 'elk/broker',
          {
            type: '_count',
            index: VENTAS_INDEX,
            query: createQueryByEmpAndType(emp.nid, 'Menudeo', inicial, final),
          },
          {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-CSRF-Token': tk,
            },
            withCredentials: true,
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          salesByemp.push(response.data.count);
          setSales([...salesByemp]); // Asegúrate de usar el operador spread (...) para crear una nueva matriz y desencadenar una actualización en el estado
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error, 'error getquerysales');
        });
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []); // Agrega un arreglo vacío [] como dependencia para asegurarte de que useEffect se ejecute solo una vez al montar el componente

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Renderiza el componente hijo solo si sales tiene valores */}
      {sales.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {sales.map((item, index) => (
            <CardsRender item={item} index={index} key={index} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

En este ejemplo, hemos movido la lógica de getQuerySales dentro de useEffect y lo llamamos una vez al montar el componente. También hemos agregado una verificación sales.length > 0 para asegurarnos de que el componente hijo se renderice solo cuando sales tenga valores.

Comment: Fijate que  tu logica es para sacar las cards la verdad eso ya lo tengo implementado y corriendo bien con flatlist, ahora flatlist ya esta renderizando las card pero tengo otro arreglo  que quiero correrlo junto con sales pero al recargar la app me sale el error cannot read propery "x" of undefined,  cuando consoleo el array este los primeros 3 salen vacios y despues ya recorre bien, no se si sea eso

Comment: Mire, return(
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled={false} // this line is important
        data={sales}
        keyExtractor= {(item, index)=> index}
        renderItem={({item,index})=> {
          console.log(property[index]) ---->>>>> esto renderiza lo siguiente 
          return ( los 5 objetos pero despues de los objetos me arroja 11 undefined   creo que por ahi esta el problema pero no se por donde buscar

Comment: Hola ¿Por qué Julian esta obteniendo  el error "cannot read propery "x" of undefined" ?

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys lo que pasa es que no lo se, me estoy enfrentando a que mi componente no se renderiza  hasta que doy ctrl + s ,  tal vez es eso que cuando carga y no esta el objeto, da el undefined, la verdad ya no se que hacerle